# How to dynamically create a blank row in apex:pageBlockTable if the List is blank

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

Dynamically create a blank row in apex:pageBlockTable if the List is blank

**Current Working If the List is blank**

[image]

**Required Output If List is blank**

[image]

**Sample VF Page Code Snippet**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="planTable" value="{!opportunityLineItemList}" var="opp"  width="100%" >
    <apex:column id="col1">
        <apex:facet name="header"><div style="color:#4a4a56;font-weight:bold;font-size:95% !important;"> ZXZXZZ <span class="requiredf">* </span></div></apex:facet>
        <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectedPlanId" value="{!opp.Pioning__c}" disabled="true" />
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column id="col2"> 
        <apex:facet name="header"><div style="color:#4a4a56;font-weight:bold;font-size:95% !important;"> Product <span class="requiredf">* </span></div></apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText ><a href= "/{!opp.Id}" target="_blank">{!opp.Product2.Name}</a></apex:outputText> 
   </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display a message, you can easily do that as below. Use a `<apex:outputText` to show the message and rendered it based on the list size `rendered="{!contacts.size==0}"`. I used an HTML `<table` element to center-align the message. The number in the `colspan="2"` attribute should be same as no of columns present in the table.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountHelper">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Account">
      <apex:outputField value="{!account.name}"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Related Contacts">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="ct">
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header"><span>Name</span></apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="{!ct.name}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header"><span>Phone</span></apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="{!ct.phone}"/>
          </apex:column>          
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:outputText rendered="{!contacts.size==0}">
          <table width="100%">
              <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Records</td></tr>
          </table>
      </apex:outputText>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

> Update -- Adding a border to the table.

To add a border similar to `<apex:pageBlockTable` you can use CSS border attribute as below. You can adjust the width of the border as per your requirement.

```
<table width="100%" style="border-style: solid; border-color: #e0e3e5;border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;">
```

Screenshot:

Without border
[image]

With Border
[image]

> Update: Using existing `<apex:pageBlockTable` rather than adding another html table structure.

In this case, we will get the table created by `<apex:pageBlockTable` through JavaScript and append a row with the text "*No Records*" in case there is no record available.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountHelper">
  <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"/>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Account">
      <apex:outputField value="{!account.name}"/>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Related Contacts">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="ct" id="myTable">
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header"><span>Name</span></apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="{!ct.name}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:facet name="header"><span>Phone</span></apex:facet>
              <apex:outputText value="{!ct.phone}"/>
          </apex:column>          
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!contacts.size==0}">
            $j("[id$=myTable]").append('<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Records</td></tr>');
        </apex:outputText>
    });
  </script>  
</apex:page>
```

Screen:

[image]

Comment: Actually i am not looking for this because if you see the required output screen shot the table has column that has border.

Comment: @RCS To get the border you can add border style attribute to the table. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes that might work but we are creating a new table instead of binding that to a actual pageBlock table.

Comment: @RCS Yes you can use the existing table created by `<apex:pageBlockTable` through JS. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Same thing i implemented but with a plain javascript by creating a dynamic row for pageBlock table and not using JQuery. BTW thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways

1. If the 'opportunityLineItemList' list is empty, create an empty record of opportunityLineItem in database, get the list & display it on page & then data will get bind to list once the user enter/change the values on page, So displaying blank row on page problem will get solved.

   ```
   if(opportunityLineItemList == null) { 
     opportunityLineItem newRec = new opportunityLineItem(); 
     insert newRec;
     opportunityLineItemList.add(newRec ); 
   }
   ```

then display this opportunityLineItemList in pageblockSection

2. If u don't want to insert the empty record in database, then instead of binding List ie.'opportunityLineItemList' bind a list (ie. Wrapper Class of opportunityLineItem let's say 'opportunityLineItemWrapper'). So if the opportunityLineItemWrapperlst is empty, add new record of opportunityLineItemWrapper to opportunityLineItemWrapperlst & display it on pageblocktable.

   ```
   public List<opportunityLineItemWrapper> opportunityLineItemWrapperlst {get;set;} 
   public class opportunityLineItemWrapper {// same fields as opportunityLineItem with get set property public Id OppLineItemId{get;set;} public datatype fieldname {get;set} }

   if(opportunityLineItem != null) { //copy over data to opportunityLineItemWrapperlst lst by iterating the opportunityLineItem in for loop 
   } else { 
        opportunityLineItemWrapperlst =  new    List<opportunityLineItemWrapper>(); 
        opportunityLineItemWrapper newWrapperRec = new opportunityLineItemWrapper (); 
        opportunityLineItemWrapperlst.add(newWrapperRec); 
   }
   ```

Hope this will help you.